# How to create the URI for condition OR in Bugzilla using C#

Tags: c#, bugzilla

I have to make a search in bugzilla for different conditions, depends on what the user select.
For example, i want to search in the same time, for bugs that have :

(STATUS_BUG = In Progress **AND** Version_Bug = 1) **OR** (STATUS_BUG = NEW **AND** Version_Bug = 0)

Version_Bug it's a  custom field, added by me. 
I don't know how to create the url from code, for condition OR. I've tried to use the advance search filter, but the url it looks very ugly.

Thanks in advance,
Andreea.